# "More than convinced " meaning?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

"Im more than convinced,  she didn't attend the class."
 What does this phrase mean here? I googled it too,  but the effort went all in vain.

Answer (score 1):

In this usage, "more than" indicates that whatever threshold would be required to "convince" the speaker has been exceeded, by such an amount that there is no uncertainty or equivocation.

Common examples of this usage:

- more than convinced / persuaded
- more than satisfied / happy

Answer (score 0):

The phrase [**more than**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/more-than) basically means *very*. For example, these two statements are more or less equivalent in meaning:

> I will be **more than** willing to help you solve this problem.
>
> I will be **very** willing to help you solve this problem.

So, here's how you can understand your original sentence:

> I'm **very** convinced that she didn't attend the class.